# Why are part-time jobs in programming an anomaly?

Tags: organization

I've recently quit my full time developing job at mega-corp, and I decided that I'll look for a part time job. Since then I've talked to half a dozen potential employers, and every one of them had the same reaction when I said the magic words "part-time" - they all closed up and became suspicious. Now, I understand that it might just be me, so as control I asked every one of them what if I were willing to work full time, and they all said I would probably get an offer.

My question is two fold:

1. Why, as an employer, would you give up a competent, even great, developer, simply because he wants to work 3 days a week and not 5?
2. How do I sell the story of part time job better? I usually just list my reasons which are that I prefer that balance currently in my life and that I want to work on my own projects, but it leaves them even more suspicious - am I going to start something myself and quit? Am I just lazy?

Comment: Related, but the answers are really specific to students, which I'm not - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/best-way-to-find-part-time-programming-work-while-at-uni

Comment: Yes, it's an anomaly. OTOH, a part-time admin is a very welcome, especially in small companies that neither need nor can afford a full-time admin.

Comment: From what I hear, a large number of employers would give up a competent, even great, developer simply because he wants to work 5 days a week and not 7.

Comment: Why don't you want to work full time?  Got a job elsewhere?

Comment: 3 days a week might be a bit too low, but I know programmers who have successfully negotiated 4-day weeks, at 80% the pay they would have gotten for a 5-day week.

Comment: I guess saying you want to work on your own projects may be the worst thing you could ever say. A manager wants full dedication. You might be physically at his location, staring at a screen of his code, but thinking how to solve a problem on your own project. Are you spending your time on his or on your project? Most contracts I have had expressly forbid personal projects and some even go so far as claiming the right on any patents or inventions you may have during the period you work for them. Passion, Dedication, Commitment and Patronage are the gems that contractors are looking for.

Comment: How can your emplayer forbid personal projects? Working on them during work time is a no-go anyway unless your company explictely allows it... but at home you can do pretty much whatever you want.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Because there's other stuff to do besides work on someone else's stuff.

Comment: I've seen people who are still studying working half-time, but once the degree is done, noone works part-time.

Comment: @OrbWeaver the funny thing is, a few people I talked with and stressed I'm looking for part time, have totally ignored it and offered offers to be one of the first employees, meaning of course a shit ton of work for some future reward).

Comment: @ThiefMaster, well not exactly forbidding personal projects, but any commercial activity, so no personal shareware or the likes. Concerning non-commercial open source activity, at least it shows passion and commitment to the field of profession, but if the boss will really be glad with it just depends... On my first job, I had the contract altered to allow my personal shareware site. I've now quit the shareware idea since it is impossible to combine a full-time job, a family and maintaining the shareware.

Comment: It's because 90% programmers are male and male people is not supposed to ask part time jobs.

Comment: Read this with interest, a) because I had the same experience and b) because I'm hoping to hire people in my own company some time next year and I would like to make 3-day weeks possible without being an economic jerk.

Comment: In the uk, if you have young children or are a carer you are entitled to apply for full time job and request they consider a job share. Companies are required to properly consider this request.

Comment: Why not just do short term full time contracts and take some time off between them to work on your own projects.

Comment: I tell them that I'm in grad school for my Masters degree, which is true. Most employers are sympathetic to mid-career professionals that want to further their education. I have done this successfully to the point of working 15-20 hours a week for full-time pay :-)

Comment: @MichaelShaw - Unfortunately, for a programmer in a team, they can just say "programmers need to keep up to date with changes made by other programmers; two job-sharing programmers would spend more time doing this and therefore less time working. Request denied."

Comment: @jules, that kind of response would be good evidence of a company not properly considering the part time request.  I think it would be hard to justify why adding an extra developer to the project would be so problematic.

Comment: Are they? Many of my fellow evening college students work part time. I myself work just 20 hours and it's awesome. At my current job and my last job I expected more pushback when asking for less hours but there was none.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

> Why, as an employer, would you give up a competent, even great, developer, simply because he wants to work 3 days a week and not 5?

More than one reason (all argued from the point of view of an employer):

1. As [Fred Brooks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Brooks) argues in the book *[The Mythical Man-Month](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month)*, the efficiency of a team goes down as the team size grows, because the amount of communication grows faster than linear with the team size. So N full-time developers are far more effective than 2N part-time developers, at the same cost.
2. If the developer is working on some important system, you want to be able to reach her at least during normal business hours.
3. A full time employee spends only eight hours at the office five days a week, but his mind is really working for the company 24 hours a day, seven days a week. That's why you sometimes wake up in the morning with the solution to a problem that's been bothering you for days - your mind doesn't stop working the moment you leave the office. For a part-time employee, I would fear the opposite: Instead of thinking about his day-job at home, I'd guess she'd think about her private problems at work.

> How do I sell the story of part time job better?

Actually, I think the employers are mostly right, so I don't think you can "sell" it much better. But you could find a small company that doesn't have enough work for a full-time employee. They might be interested in hiring you part-time. Jobs like that probably wouldn't be very glamorous (or well-paid), though.

**EDIT**:
Your comments suggest that your don't have much working experience and that you can't imagine spending 40 hours per week at work. I can totally relate to that, sitting 40 hours a week in the cubicle next to Dilbert and Wally *does* sound like a horrible prospect.

If that's reasonably close, forget my advice about looking for a job at a company that doesn't have enough work for a full-time employee. These jobs certainly exists, but you won't learn much there (if they have only one part-time developer, who would teach you anything?), and they don't look very good on a resume (why did he start his career doing *that*? Couldn't he find a full-time job?). They'd probably be rather boring jobs, too, and IMHO spending 20 hours a week at a boring job is worse than spending 40 hours a week working on something you care about.

Instead try to find a full-time job where you get to build something interesting, where you like your co-workers and where you genuinely like going to work each morning. These jobs really are out there, and they're easier to find than part-time positions. There's still enough time to play [StarCraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarCraft) at the weekends ;-)

Comment: I've known many full time employees who weren't thinking much about their employer's problems even during regular work hours. Some even worked on side jobs, using the employer's resources.

Comment: @Péter - Google even encourages employees to work on side-jobs IIRC, at least within limits and structured in a particular way.

Comment: @Steve314, I am fairly sure they aren't encouraging their employees to do paid work to another company during their regular work hours... Sorry if this wasn't clear, I didn't mean personal hobby projects.

Comment: _...his mind is really working for the company 24 hours a day, 7 days a week... ...Instead of thinking about his day-job at home..._ From a manager's point of view I can see the logic. From a human point of view this is very depressing.

Comment: @PéterTörök: True, but I guess if an employer thinks you're one of these developers, he wouldn't hire you part-time or full-time.

Comment: @MrMisterMan: If you enjoy your job, I'm not sure why? Our brains aren't computers where you can just switch a task on or off - our subconscious constantly works on things that we care about. Even if we're consciously thinking about something completely different or even sleeping at the time. We're just wired that way.

Comment: @MrMisterMan, let me add that IMHO this is a very limited manager's view (albeit sadly common). Good managers know that their employees - or rather, *colleagues* - need time to relax and recharge, otherwise they will get tired, thus start making mistakes, and eventually may even burn out - which is a much bigger loss for the company in the long run, than the few extra work hours gained in the short term.

Comment: I don't think it's depressing that you would think about work on your own time. I often do that because I like my job. It's depressing that management _expects_ it.

Comment: This saddens me a bit. I really hoped for a way to sell it better, but maybe it is as impossible as you say it is.

Comment: Accepted because you also answered part two of the question, even if it is not the answer I hoped for.

Comment: Or, you could find a full-time job where you get to build something interesting, where you like your co-workers and where you genuinely like going to work each morning AND where you play StarCraft as well :)

Comment: @Jakob: *Those* jobs are even better, but harder to find, too.

Comment: Well, your edit is kinda off, I've been working full time for the past two years which I liked (well, the first year and a half), and even though I'm young I'm pretty experienced (5+ years). I'm quite conflicted now since I'm getting a lot of really great offers, but all of them want me for at least 5 days a week :) I guess I need to do some heavy thinking, maybe visit philosophy stack exchange :)

Comment: @Mikle: Oh, I hope I didn't offend you, then. That was not the intention. I just wanted to say that the kind of part-time jobs I can think of aren't very good for gathering experience or for your future CV.

Comment: It's a bit sexist to assume that the part-time employee is a she while the fulltime one is a he ...

Comment: @Otomo: Then why do you assume that? I didn't even think about that until you mentioned it. I simply used male and female pronouns randomly, like I always do.

Comment: @nickie Didn't seem random to me - my mistake

Answer (score 41):

Asking for a part-time job without further explanation looks like you don't *really* want to work for them.

It may looks like you will use them until you don't need them anymore.

Here are few issues your employer may see in that proposal:

- For the same amount of "work", you will duplicate their problems: 2x communication, 2x administative work (sick days, holidays, ...), 2x more risk to have to start the hiring process again...
- If your colleagues or your boss(es) *really* need an information from you, the probability to be unable to reach you is 0.5.
- Your colleague may not understand your particular situation as well.

Working like that will be really feasible if the employer is actively looking for a part-time programmer. One of the most common reason is that they can't afford one full programmer. This may give you hints to make a list of potential employers, such as small businesses not specifically working in the software field.

Comment: Agreed, if they're not already looking for a part-time employee, they're probably not interested in a part-time employee.

Comment: Plus, you will be unavailable almost half of the time your colleagues need you.

Comment: @DeanHarding I am very candid with the fact that I'm looking for part time, both in the initial mail and phone conversation and when asked. If they aren't looking for part time, why are they interviewing me in the first place and more importantly why do they try and get me to work full time?

Comment: @Mikle: Hmm, that does seem unusual then. If you've explicitly said you're looking for part-time, and they interviewed you anyway, it kind of indicates they're not really paying attention... or maybe they think they can convince you otherwise after the interview?

Comment: @DeanHarding I've interviewed with 4 people, our of the 2 found some stuff I can do half time or as a freelancer, and 2 were adamant about full time. I've also talked to a few other people, all of them said "just keep an open mind for a full time position" which is an Israeli way of saying they are looking for full time :)

Comment: *It may looks like you will use them until you don't need them anymore.* Companies use employees as tools and dump them whenever they don't need them (I have personal experience). It is fair for us to do the same instead of one-sided manipulation.

Answer (score 37):

One reason is that, as a manager, you get an ok to recruit one "head". Not fractions. One.
This means, if you recruit someone part-time, you'll have to all effects one person in your team that does 3/5 of the work he/she's supposed to do or you will have to hire another person who wants to work the remaining 2/5.
However you see it, this turns quickly into an organizational problem in terms of coordination, effort, communication...
I think your best chance to work part time is to work as a consultant and do only the specific hours you need on the projects you're hired for.

Comment: Sad but true, bureaucracy over people

Comment: The thing is I don't really want to be a free lancer yet. I'm still pretty young, and I prefer to work with people and learn from them.

Comment: @lechlukasz - it is not "bureaucracy", it's management. Just because something looks simple and trivial to you doesn't mean it is. Just because something looks free to you isn't necessarily so (e.g. a marginal cost to the business to have an extra employee)

Answer (score 37):

Great question.

There's some good answers hereabouts too, but overwhelmingly they appear to be taking the employers' perspective, so let me redress that a little.

Firstly, I think it is great that you are wanting to take a better work/life balance than an ordinary 9-6 job will offer you. We who live in advanced capitalist economies often need reminding that our society has created a 'normal' workaholism that takes from most people most of their useful waking hours. You may therefore need a bit of encouragement in your quest, and I would start with recommending [How to Be Idle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0141015063) by Tom Hodgkinson. In it he argues for a de-stressed society that lives cheaply, works less, makes more merriment and relies less on expensive/pre-packaged food and entertainment (I believe his How To Be Free is on similar lines, and I forget which one it was that I have read).

I'd also say that you shouldn't mention your part-time intentions until you've got through first-stage interview. You can then ask at second stage interview, or via email/telephone contact, if your application progresses.

Consider also only asking for four days/week. For some reason, I sense there is quite a gulf between three and four - maybe because Friday tends to be a wind-down day, and a good programmer cannot be expected to run at full productivity five days a week anyway. So I think you'd be more likely to get a nod if you start asking small.

Also, would you consider taking a flexitime job on with full-time hours? That would be nine-ish hours per day rather than seven-ish, but would mean that your employer gets the benefit of a full-time developer whilst giving you the win you're after. That of course presumes you'd be happy with just one extra day off per week. Incidentally, some while back I noticed a tasty-looking advert on StackExchange for a four-day week dev based in San Francisco - so they are out there (edit: I wanted to link to it but cannot find it - it is probably gone!).

That last point brings me to my next one: apply to small companies or start-ups. Small firms don't often have the budget to pay good developers handsomely, so they may offer non-remuneration benefits instead. Also, there are less layers of middle-management to get unusual requests rubber-stamped.

My path has been somewhat similar to yours - I used to work for a large company as a PHP/Oracle web programmer, and they insisted on my commuting to the office every day, resulting in 300 miles per week of pointless mileage. I requested flexitime and home-working at various strategic points (reviews and the like) and they were repeatedly "considered" and turned down. I enjoyed the job and the people, but a couple of years later, I gave up asking, found a small UK company that offered both flexitime and telecommuting, and resigned from the corporate job. It is my hope that in leaving over it, I have *very slightly* improved the chances of others who want to do the same.

So, I wish you the best of luck - if you are successful in this endeavour, you also may help out other developers who feel the same as you do. If you get there, do document somewhere on the web some tips to help others!

Edits: an [interesting article and comments](http://thinkvitamin.com/fully-carsonified/work-less/) on this topic, and [another](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1209-forbes-misses-the-point-of-the-4-day-work-week) from 37signals. [Here](http://www.inc.com/guides/2010/04/4-day-work-week.html) is how companies can set up four-day working weeks. Less on-topic but very interesting - [remote working](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/05/on-working-remotely.html) by the chap who set up this very website!

Comment: It's true that "advanced capitalist society" has brought us the 40 hour week. Before that, average people had to work 10-16 hours a day, 7 days a week. And if the crop failed, they would still starve.

Comment: Depends how far you go back in history - you're only going back to the Victorian age. I recommended the Hodgkinson book as he examines the work patterns of the Middle Ages - some farm labourers worked one or two days a week! I'm not arguing that other periods of human history have been idyllic, however. But I *am* saying that (a) 40 hours per week is a lot of day-time to give up, (b) it would be great if some people could choose to work less hours for less money, and (c) we should all spend more time with friends, family or on hobbies. My view is that we would benefit societally from it.

Comment: "some farm labourers worked one or two days a week". Sure, but they were hungry the other 5-6 days...

Comment: No, but I sense that we have political differences emerging, which is straying quite off-topic. Happy to agree to disagree :)

Comment: Great answer halfer. I am applying mostly to startups and small companies, but it is so easy to get seeded today that most of them have too much money to throw at me to work full time. Also, I live in Israel, so a job in SF will probably be a bit tough to hold :) Thanks for the links, interesting reads.

Comment: Heh, yes, since I am in the UK, the US West Coast is a bit of a commute on my bicycle ;-). Since you're in Israel, a good long term plan might be to develop links with the cost-of-living movements your country has seen this year. There's sure to be individuals within those groups who feel the same way you do about life/work priorities.

Answer (score 18):

Most answers I see are rationalizations for the status quo, but really, **I don't think there is a good reason for this state of things**. Most programmers seem to believe *not having a life is part of the deal* and spoil it for the rest of us. Managers are good at screwing everybody around, unions are a joke, everybody says the economy sucks, but then there's always a need for programmers, and this should be exploited by the category.

Also I'm kind of flustered no-one pointed out that a wonderful reason for asking for a part-time job, would be **"having a kid."**

As soon as a critical mass of people starts asking for part-time programming jobs, there will be plenty of offerings. So go on, and convince more people to do the same. This is the closest we get to a union battle.

Comment: this reads more like a rant than an answer. As for point about family reasons, it was made in at least two prior answers posted years before ([1](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/121537/31260), [2](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/121490/31260))

Comment: "There is no good reason" is the point of the answer. The fact workers in the field don't get it, might be the rant. Or a deeper truth to deal with, or both.

Answer (score 7):

I can think of a couple of reasons.

1. Companies that employ software developers recognise that they are developing a product to give them some sort of business advantage (eg: direct revenue, a process, etc...). Regardless of the specifics of the advantage, the company is going to want to jealously protect their intellectual property. Yes, company execs can be a very suspicious lot when it comes to this sort of thing, so in their minds they might be thinking, 'why does this person only want to work for me part of the time? Is this person working for someone else? Could this person become a risk to my IP?'
2. Companies are generally hiring people because they have determined a resourcing requirement that entails the need for a person to be working on a project for a certain amount of time in order to meet specific deadlines and targets.  The view therefore is that someone working part time will not allow them to fulfil the resourcing requirement in it's entirety, and;

   a) The employer doesn't wish to face a need to employ additional staff,

   b) There may be additional costs associated with hiring multiple part time staf in terms of benefits, payroll taxes, etc.
3. You are asking for a part time position when an advertised job may have specified full time.  Sometimes people think it strange that a candidate does not seem to have understood the requirements specified in a job description, and that this might suggest if such simple directions are not followed, perhaps the candidate won't pay attention to specifications.
4. You may have unwittingly presented the option in a way that makes it seem suspicious.
5. Perhaps the interviewer has already decided not to hire you, and unwittingly gives away a negative reaction to a question they feel is no longer relevant.

Just a few thoughts...  realistically speaking, most jobs in software development require full time staff.  You may later earn an option to shift to part time work, or you may find one of the rare roles out there that allow this, but it's likely to be hard.

As to specifically answering your first question, I'd answer that with, why would an employer give up the option for a programmer working entirely for his company's benefit full time for someone who the employer feels will only be putting in an effort for part of the time?

Answer (score 7):

A thought that strikes me as I read the other well thought out answers is that if you want part time work, why aren't you considering short term contract positions?  In this area, that is the norm for developers who want free time to work on their own projects.

This way you can usually work off site and manage your own time, be confident in your earnings and still know that you'll have time to work on your projects.  Work 3 months full time, take the next 2 off.  During that 2 you line up your next contracts.

Comment: Working as a freelancer is a hassle. You need to actively seek out clients, advertise yourself and deal with clueless managers. Also, it is quite lonely, while I want to work with a development team to learn from.

Comment: @Mikle You can't have everything. Stephen gave you a good answer. I had a difficult time finding my first part-time job as a programmer, as a contractor. I did get something, 20 hours a week, for $50/hr for 6 months. And I actually ended up working around 30-35 hrs a week to get the job done. I couldn't bill all that time, cause the company didn't have the budget for it, and I wasn't going to just quit. There are lots of agencies that will actively seek YOU as a freelancer, if you are skilled.

Comment: @Mikle I think you're going to have to prioritize what you want.  Co-workers are not really there to teach you, though that happens quite frequently.  If you're still learning your craft, you might want to dive in and work full time.  There will be time for side projects, just less of it.

Comment: @FeralOink I think I'm young enough to strive and get what I want. I gave myself a two month limit on this search, if I don't find a part time job I'll either become a contractor or go full time (or start my own thing) but I'm definitely not gonna give up without trying.
Stephen, aren't we all learning our craft all the time? How can you say that coworkers are not there to teach, since this is the essence of a team - working together and learning from one another. I can be an expert with 40 years of experience and still learn from someone who just graduated.

Comment: @Mikle Now that sounds like a really good idea: Give yourself two months to find what you really want. That is totally reasonable! With an attitude like that, and a contingency plan in place for day one of month 3, well, maybe you won't still be looking 3 months from now. Some people are VERY rigid, uncompromising. Doesn't seem like that describes you, in which case you'll do fine. Set limits, make plans, yet be willing to compromise. Good luck!

Comment: @Mikle - I'll put it as nicely as possible. When a green newbie shows up at my team, I have to spend close to 50% of my 10-hour-long work days for a couple of weeks (and 25% for months) to teach them and bring them up to speed on stuff. That's a VERY expensive proposition to be wasted on "team" member who'd like the easy life and would not bother contributing to the team full time for a significant period of time (and your part time stance screams "will quit soon"). So no, people don't want to teach someone like you.

Comment: @FeralOink Thank you.

dvk: Do you know me? If not you have no reason to talk about people like me. I think you are assuming too many things. I'm sure that if you'll work 8 hours a day you'll be happier and less condescending :)

Answer (score 6):

There's lots of things that may factor in, such as the longer the time between working, the more you've forgotten and the longer it takes to figure out where you left off, reducing the productivity.

There's also the widespread (and largely justified) view that great developers want to develop - that the issue is preventing them from burning themselves out, and that developers who want to work fewer hours are not great almost by definition.

Probably the key factor, though, is that you're basically asking employers to pay the full cost of bringing you up to speed etc, despite only offering around 60% (at best) of the payoff. Would you pay the full price for a 60% share of the ownership of a computer (excluding Apple owners).

Of course in real life it's a more complex formula than that, as productivity depends on a lot of factors and is never constant through all your working hours unless its constantly zero - but the complexity of that formula argues against at least as much as for your position. For example, less intensive learning is usually slower learning - bigger gaps mean more is forgotten between times.

Comment: I like your second point (about developers being expected to just love coding so much that employers are basically doing them a favor when giving them some more work for the weekend)

Comment: I love coding. I also live riding bikes, playing Starcraft and being out while the sun is still shining, something full time jobs lack. I also have tens of ideas of my own I want to work on.

Comment: To those who are telling that the problems is relatively high cost of educating - the worker could accept lower salary while on period when he is new and not knowing the software. Or if he is being educated with the new technologies which makes him having higher value at the market, he could accept those hours being free or something like that.

Answer (score 6):

The explanations are important.

- I would hope that a modern employer would recognise *work-life balance* as a reasonable goal. Especially if you have a family or some similar responsibility.
- I would not say that you want to *work on your own projects*, which will make the employer suspect that you might goof off and work on them when you should be working for the employer, or that you might quit soon to work on them full time.
- You could say that you already have a *part-time commitment* and you need some more part-time work to build up your income. Make the part-time commitment sound commercial. For example "I need to do a little support for some existing clients" is good, it gives an impression that you have some business sense. "I want to work on my own projects" is less good, it gives the impression that you might goof off to work on a pet open-source project.

Comment: I'm sure most employers recognise work-life balance as a reasonable goal. As long as you do it in your spare time. ;-)

Comment: I would hope it too

Comment: You are probably right, I will not say the work on my own projects from on.

Comment: Its not fair imo that employee expect you to not have personal projects and dream to have your own company, when he himself some time ago had started from those projects also. Or do they think - if you want your own business, you have to have savings and leave job and start risking and working on it full time? we know that its nonsence, very low % of startups end up good.

Answer (score 6):

That's probably a form of supplier induced demand. As long as there are lots of programmers willing to dedicate their whole day (and night) time to work, there is no reason for the employer to accept any extra-effort with uncertain extra-outcomes by following uncommon employment policies.
So unless a growing fraction of developers starts recognizing the benefits of part-time employment and start demanding it from their employers, it is unlikely that these change their policy for those reasons stated in the other posts.

I think this isn't a specific programmers issue. Most employments that are traditionally assigned to the male gender are full-time by definition. Because, traditionally, men care for the cash flow and women care for the family. While women nowadays also claim to get a work-life, the male role model is yet a full-time work, spare-time private projects model.
So, up to now the emancipation of women came at the cost of the family aspect of life.
Decreasing birth rates and increasing public child care tell a story.

The point of this, the emancipation of men, that will allow men to prefer family over the job, is the next step of the emancipation of women. 
To relate back to part-time programmers: this is a matter of role models and society, and not a question of what extras the employers are willing to grant to their employees.
I think in a healthy society there will be an equilibrium state where both (or all, whatever) genders are equally doing a bit of work, and a bit of family, and a bit of private projects.

Related links (to be continued):

- http://www.ted.com/talks/anne_marie_slaughter_can_we_all_have_it_all

Comment: So what does an early adopter like me do? :( The market here is in high demand for programming talent, but only full time. Even 80% is almost universally denied.

Comment: Start your own business, if you are creative. Don't be too focussed on programming. Smart people are needed everywhere.

Comment: +1 for recommending The Idler - see my response :)

Comment: This (and gd1's comment on the question) are the only answers that get to the root of the issue. And the solution to the problem is: MORE WOMEN IN PROGRAMMING.

Answer (score 5):

You may think of yourself as a programmer who wants to work 3/5 of a week. If you are applying for jobs at a company large enough to have a HR department then here are a few of your problems:

It's a tight market and you are responding to a full-time position with a counter-offer for part-time work. Resumes are being thrown away for lack of "optional" requirements and you just wasted their time by interviewing for a job (full-time) that you didn't intend to take. From their point of view - you lied.

As previously mentioned they have a 1.0 programming unit requirement and you are 0.6 programming unit - bad fit.

If they hire full-time employees and full-time contractors you don't fit HR systems - payroll, insurance eligibility, real estate (do you get 3/5 of a desk? do they waste 2/5 of a desk?).

From the manager's point of view you are just as big a headache - dress code, email appropriateness, late arrivals, sexual harassment - as everyone who is doing 166% of the work you do.

The previous comments about project complexity (and things like company limits on the number of direct reports) hold true. Imagine a project that requires 1 developer. Now imagine running that project with five 1/5 developers. It's an exaggeration but it points up the issue.

If the ad or referrer doesn't say "part-time", don't bother. You're wasting everyone's time. You might consider a serial part-time career. Work for nine months then take three off. You'll need to find something to put on your resume to cover the three months though.

Comment: I don't think the "work 9 months, then quit" strategy is good advice. It's quite unfair to employers (they invest the full cost for bringing you up to speed, but don't get the benefits) and after a few times, you won't get invited job interviews any more, because everyone looks at your resume and thinks "wow, he can't be any good, no company wanted to keep him longer than a few months".

Comment: Agree with nikie on this point - in the UK at least, if you have too much *CV bounce*, companies may think you'll leave just as soon as you've got up to full productive speed. Some way of getting a good long-term employer-employee relationship is required whilst still attaining your part-time goals.

Comment: You may well be right about "bounce". I tried to answer the question from the perspective of the employer and make suggestions form the perspective of the questioner. That is, someone who interviews for full-time jobs and counterproposes part-time work. It's not something I would do but given that it *is* something the questioner would do I thought the 9 month/3 month idea was more likely to land him a job than the "3/5 compromise" (US history joke).

Comment: some people ask for job even when company is not searching for worker. So its the same. They are not searching for part time worker, but maybe it will fit. Also why they accpet students part time? The same problems exist - 1/2 desk, etc. I guess those problems can be solved by employee paying himself for the remaining 1/2 desk by getting lower salary.

Answer (score 4):

A development team can be considered a [fully connected network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully-connected_network), which means there are n(n - 1) / 2 "interfaces" between the developers. In practice this means that going from five to seven developers, the team suddenly has more than twice the opportunity for friction, communications failures and misunderstandings.

Answer (score 4):

The points about efficiency and overhead (both bureaucratic and in the N^2 interpersonal effects) seem valid, but here's a more jaded take: employers of coders don't want any limitation at all on the hours they can ask of you.   They're used to being able to ask developers to work 50, 60, in my experience as much as 80 hours in some weeks for no extra pay (and on hourly contracts to lie about your hours, or it's go look for another job...which eventually I did do, but many can't or in any event won't).   Someone who starts by limiting their hours to a nominal (say) 24/wk doesn't sound like someone who will be willing to work  40 for the same wages when asked to so do,  for reasons decent (deadlines)  and indecent ('We need the shares price to rise a few pennies for a few weeks, so let's fire a few people and let the others, cowed by the firings, take on the work their former colleagues performed, ').

Note: if you've a reputation as a wizard,  you can in fact get part-time work, as some will feel blessed that they get any of you at all---this is related to why rock-stars tend to have a lot of casual sex (because they can, because enough potential partners value such so, and because social norms are actually *enforced* by allowing exceptional people to violate them---'Sure,  Steven Tyler [or rms]  can act that way, but you're not in his league, don't get uppity,').

Answer (score 3):

Everyone seems to be quoting Brooks and making efficiency arguments, none of which are particularly *wrong*, mind you, but I think they've missed a rather essential point.  Programming is, generally speaking, a lot more art than science.  Oh sure, you can get a CS degree and learn a heck a lot about algorithms and solving "typical problems" at a good school and thus increase your knowledge of the science side substantially, but the only CS grads I've ever seen go on to truly become Software Engineers (vs taking detours into marketing, sales or non-engineering management) were the ones who truly loved it and considered 40 hours a week to be insufficient, if anything, because they loved to create things and writing software was a particularly satisfying way of doing just that.  I'm not saying that all software engineers need to be artists at heart, but the very best ones are, and no employer will ever say "I'm looking for the 2nd or 3rd best over here!  Keep those resumes coming, please!"

By saying you only want to work part-time, you're essentially telling a prospective employer that you're just not that into it in comparison to the other candidates who are devoting every waking hour to software and contributing their work to various open source projects when no better outlet for their creativity is available.  If an analogy will help, imagine your next restaurant meal:  Who do you want to make it?  Somebody who doesn't really care about cooking and is just slapping your meal together or a chef who really loves cooking?

Comment: "you're essentially telling a prospective employer that you're just not that into it" +1. That's *exactly* the point.

Comment: @jkh and nikie - from the perspective of the employer this may look like that, but that's just a stigma or a stereotype. I can be just as productive, caring and professional 3 days a week as 5.

Comment: @Mikle Stereotype or not, how it looks from the perspective of the employer is all that really matters here since you're still competing in the workplace against people who don't have that stipulation.  Perhaps in 20 years or so, the notion of a fixed work week will be dead and you'll have simply been ahead of your time. :)

Comment: I suspect there are a lot of programmers who are deeply into it, but not deeply into losing so many hours to crud servitude that they could be spending on really interesting stuff.

Comment: "imagine your next restaurant meal: Who do you want to make it?"  Someone who is good at cooking.  Couldn't care less if they have passion & enthusiasm, so long as they have skill.

Comment: @JasonMcVetta is exactly right.  Passion doesn't matter.  It just makes you a better slave.  A job is a contract where you trade time/code for money.  If an employee is putting consideration to how much he likes the company, his co-workers, his boss, etc., he is already a loser.  The employer is within his right to and in many respects should be using stereotypes to judge candidates.  When you have many candidates and limited information, that's the best you can do.  On the other side, if I am highly skilled in producing the code you want, you're better off hiring me than someone who sucks.

Comment: @jkh: Many people are passionate about programming *and* also passionate about other things, like music, art, theater, writing, etc.  The more artistic someone is, the more interests he/she will have, and the harder it will be for him/her to spend most of his/her usable waking hours doing only one thing.  By limiting yourself to full-time employees, you miss many of the most creative, artistic people.  Or, by tying them down to only one thing, they come to resent programming instead of being passionate about it.  Either way, the full-time-only culture represents a loss for the entire industry.

Comment: The employers have a lot to choose from? This does not look like being reality in my area at least and I believe in many cities its also the same. So that makes it interesting, why its hard to get such. If it was easy for them to get a programmer, then there would not be so many job advertisements and head hunting.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the bases have been covered.  You could try looking for a company that allows more flexible working.  For example, my company allows 2 people to share a job.  You agree with a colleague doing the same job which days you work and get paid on a pro rata basis.  I have considered taking advantage of another scheme that basically allows me to work only during school hours on school days to allow me to care for my daughter.
That said, however, they are only open, so far as I know, to established employees.

Comment: I've been considering a teaching position, but I don't think this is plausible. Maybe an instructor, but the pay isn't great.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified the sector you're looking in, but I suspect there's two main reasons:

- Suspicion about what you're doing the rest of the time (are you there to steal data, ideas, or other intellectual property (IP))
- Concerns that other employees will also want to work part-time (and the difficulty of denying parity)

There is a per-employee overhead in any business, and whilst one part-time postion may not break the bank, the overhead from a 20-person team turning into a 40-person team could be prohibitive (if no more hours are being worked) - there'd also be additional management costs coordinating such an environment.

Comment: I think your point about denying parity is well made: +1. I suspect that was one reason my requests for flexitime and home-working were turned down at my previous employer. Other people had also asked, and permitting one might have opened the floodgates!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding "How do I sell the story of part time job better"
you might think of a two stepped approach:
First find a small company where HR policy is flexible.
Work there for a year as a full time.

After a year, when they had a chance to get a positive impression of you and your work habits, ask to reduce your workload (e.g. 'I plan on doing a degree part time')

Comment: I'm not going to downvote you but I completely disagree with this. The best approach is to be firm in your requirements *from the beginning*. If part-time is what you desire, then make it clear that these are the only terms you'll accept and work from that. People will respect you "sticking to your guns" more than you think.